# In Season 4 of Brockmire, are the writers showing life imitates art?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, brockmire

Season 4 makes an immediate jump from 2020 to 2030. Beyond warnings of global warming, and other environmental tragedies like the Amazon Forest going up in flames, The writers save the best for last: the "mutant version of Lassa Fever". Eerily similar to COVID-19, the show's fever is in the process of taking down Arizona as a state, while apparently already having taken out three other states.

This was written last year, sometime, and it just seems a little too convenient. Have any of the show's writers commented on these coincidences?

Comment: HahhahA      I tried tagging it w more appropriate descriptive words, but you have to pick between the tags that have already been written...and there was a time travel on the show - (ha) it jumped from 2020 to 2030....yes I know that’s not what it means...but given the other tags to choose from.

Comment: Bottom line is that I had a legit question- and didn’t realize that this was a place that was based on a point system.

If you haven’t seen the show, or don’t understand, there’s no need to try to make it fit into a perfect little box.

Comment: I'm sorry that your first experience on Stack Exchange has been a negative one. Rest assured that your question wasn't closed because of your low reputation, or because the close-voters haven't seen the show. It was closed because it's too vague. If you can update it to be clearer, it can be re-opened.

Comment: I don’t know why this was closed. The wording could be tweaked but the fundamental question of “have the writers of the show commented on the similarities of the plot to current ongoing events?” Is fairly clear.

Comment: @Darren I've re-worded the question slightly based on your suggestion, and voted to re-open. Still not sure about the title but the actual body of the question seems fine now.

Comment: @F1Krazy I was going to do that myself but thought it might be better for the asker to take ownership. Alas, trigger-happy close voting appears to have scared off another new user.